# Recursion to find the number of occurrences of a specified character in a string

Tags: java, recursion

I have seen the solution to this question here, but the persons code is different from mine. I just want to know what I am doing wrong. I am very new to programming and desperate to be good.

Question: (Occurrences of a specified character in a string) Write a recursive method that finds the number of occurrences of a specified character in a string using the following header:

```
public static int count(String str, char a)
```

For example: `count("Welcome", 'e')` returns `2`. Write a test program that prompts the user to enter a string followed by a character and displays the number of occurrences of the character in the string.

Issue with my code:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise18_10{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string");   
        String str = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a character");   
        char car = input.next().charAt(0);
        int x = count ("welcome", 'e');
        System.out.println("The number of character " +car + " in string " +str + "     = "+ x);
    }//main

    public static int count(String str, char a){
        int ct = 0;    
        if(str.length()>0)
            if(str.charAt(0) == a)
                ct ++;
        count(str.substring(1),a);
        return ct;
    }
}
```

Help please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please learn to format your code.

Comment: One problem is that you are throwing away the result of your recursive call to `count`, instead of adding it to `ct`.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you get into the habit of **ALWAYS** using `{` and `}` characters for a branch or a loop.  If you put your `{` and `}` characters in the appropriate places in your code here, I believe you'll see immediately what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. Now I know what I was doing wrong and finally I have a better understanding of recursion. Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct; you need to check the length of the string before calling `str.substring(1)`. However, you don't need another method to maintain the `ct` variable. Here is a Java 101 appropriate answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise18_10 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a word: ");
    String word = input.next();
    System.out.print("Please enter a character: ");
    char c = input.next().charAt(0);
    int count = count(word, c);
    System.out.println(String.format("%d occurrences of %c in '%s'", count, c, word));
  }

  public static int count(String str, char a) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    if (str.charAt(0) == a) {
      count++;
    }
    return count + count(str.substring(1), a);
  }


}
```

Comment: Your welcome. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark. Welcome to StackOverflow and best of luck with your class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the index out of range error must be because of `count(str.substring(1),a);` when you reach the case where your string only has one letter and you try to get the string thats left without it, which is none.

ps: after you fix that, you should also check how you're adding and keeping the value of your ct variable...

Comment: Thanks  you so much

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error, what happens when you continuously `substring(1)`? You'll eventually get an empty string that you can't substring! Your `if str.length() > 0` isn't preventing the `substring` call.

Another problem - the `ct` variable is being reset to 0 everytime you call the method because it is scoped locally to the method.

You *could* make `ct` a static variable, but the way I would approach the problem - implement another method to maintain a `ct` variable parameter.

```
private static int countHelper(String str, char a, int count){
    if (str == null || str.length() <= 0) return count; // End recursion

    if(str.charAt(0) == a)
        count++; // Increment count

    // No need for an else statement, recurse with substring
    return countHelper(str.substring(1), a, count);
}
```

Then, your actual method just delegates to the other one

```
 public static int count(String str, char a) { 
     return countHelper(str, a, 0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write   `count(str.substring(1), a)`in the   `if{...}`  .
The other major problem in your code is that the `count` can't be preserved in rescurve,you should make the `count`static or change your code as below.

```
public static int count(String str, char a) {
    int ct = 0;
    if (str.length() > 0) {
        if (str.charAt(0) == a)
            ct++;
        ct += count(str.substring(1), a);
    }
    return ct;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int count(String str, char a) {
    int ct = 0;    
    if (str.length() > 0) {
        if (str.charAt(0) == a) {
            ct++;
        }
        return ct + count(str.substring(1), a);
    }
    return ct;
}
```

With recursive functions, always figure out the termination condition and exit the function from there, with a default value if applicable. In this case, return with count `0` if the length of the string is 0. Call your function again in the other case (where string length is greater than 0).

Also, you'll need to return the value of the function and the count as a sum to get the final total of the counts to the first call of your function.

Comment: Thank you very much